# Error creating a webhook with a scope = project id but works with top folder

Tags: webhooks, autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

When creating a webhook for a BIM360 Team project, I get the error "Access denied for the scope a.123456789 that you are trying to create hook on" when creating with the project id with the below json body and request:

https://developer.api.autodesk.com/webhooks/v1/systems/data/events/dm.version.added/hooks

```
   {
       "callbackUrl": "http://test.com/callback",
       "scope": {
            "folder": "a.123456789"
         }
    }
```

This does succeed if a top folder URN is replaced in the json.  I have tried with both 2-legged and 3-legged OAuth with data:create scope.  Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MandiBishop, adding to @Jadranko's answer, the Webhook API supports ONLY folders, so you must provide a Folder ID. Indeed the documentation is not clear and I have logged a request to improve it. Sorry about this confusion.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed two things:

1. According to [API reference](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/http/systems-system-events-event-hooks-POST/) folder member in json encoded request body should be project or folder id represented by full urn. Something like this: `urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:a.123456789`. It seems that you are sending only folder id part in your example.
2. You mentioned that you are using OAuth token with `data:create` scope. You will need `data:read` scope as well.

Documentation is a bit ambiguous about the scope. According to [this tutorial](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/tutorials/create-a-hook-data-management/#before-you-begin) `data:read` is needed for all requests plus `data:create` to create a hook. [Reference](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/http/systems-system-events-event-hooks-POST/#resource-information) mentions `data:read` + `data:write` instead.
Just go with all three to be sure, at least till you make it work.

**Update after Mandi's comment**

Well, now I see that my answer is misleading. Projects do not have id in urn form. According to [Webhooks Field Guide](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/overview/field-guide/): "Please note that, for purpose of Webhooks, *Projects* are also identified by their *Folder URN*".
It is not completely clear from the documentation but it is probably project's root folder: `data.relationships.rootFolder` in JSON data.

So if you check Project example object in [Data Management Field Guide](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/overview/field-guide/), id is probably here:

```
"rootFolder": {
    "data": {
      "type": "folders",
      "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.folder:hC6k4hndRWaeIVhIjvHu8w"
    },
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  #2 is already applied to the scope.  For #1, I only know of the Forge DM apis use ProjectId's in the form of a.123456789, not a full URN as you specify.  What would be the actual syntax for that URN? urn:adsk:wipprod:fs:project:a.123456789?